# Sending onclick event to another page

Tags: php, html, forms, button, onclick

I have a login page and what i want to do is when clicked on a button, and login info is good, it goes to index.php and hides log div and shows nova div. I have something in my code, but it doesn't work. 
Here is my code.

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location="index2.php";</script>';
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include('connection.php');

$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$pass = md5($_POST['password']);
if($user && $pass) {
$sql="SELECT * FROM korisnici WHERE username = '" . $user . "' and password = '" . $pass . "'";
if (!$q=mysql_query($sql))
{
echo "<p>Error</p>" . mysql_query();
die();
}
if (mysql_num_rows($q)==0)
{
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Incorrect username and password");      window.location="login.php";</script>';

} 
else {
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
header('Location: index.php');
}
} else {
    echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Fill out both fields!')</script>";
}
}
?>


<form action="login.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" >
Password:&nbsp <input type="password" name="password" >
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="LOGIN" name="submit" class="button" onclick="showCommentDiv()"/>
</form>
```

app.js

```
function showCommentDiv() {
document.getElementById('nova').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('log').style.display = "none";
}
```

index.php

```
<div id="log">
<form action="login.php">
<input type="submit" id="logdugme" value="LOGIN/REGISTRACIJA" name="logdugme" class="button"/>
</form> 
</div>

<div id="nova">
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <colgroup>
        <col widht="25%" style="vertical-align:top;"/>
        <col widht="75%" style="vertical-align:top;"/>
    </colgroup>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="comment" class="ime" >Comment :</label></td>
            <td><textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="50" maxlength="190" class="ime"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="dugme" name="submit" value="Leave comment"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>

    </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you display each of the divs on server side, based on `if(isset($_SESSION['username']))`?

Comment: Hm, I don't know exactly how to do that. Do you have an example of that?

Comment: I've wrote an answer because there was not enough space to post it here. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display the content you want based on your login session. Here's your index.php file for a basic example:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
?>
    <div id="log">
        <form action="login.php">
            <input type="submit" id="logdugme" value="LOGIN/REGISTRACIJA" name="logdugme" class="button"/>
        </form> 
    </div>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<div id="nova">
    <form action="#" method="POST">
        <colgroup>
            <col widht="25%" style="vertical-align:top;"/>
            <col widht="75%" style="vertical-align:top;"/>
        </colgroup>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="comment" class="ime" >Comment :</label></td>
                <td><textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="50" maxlength="190" class="ime"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="dugme" name="submit" value="Leave comment"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: @user3734349 Happy to hear that! I hope that you also understood how it's working. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

instead of :

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location="index2.php";</script>';
```

try to put :

```
header("Location: index2.php");
```

Also, try to add the following instructions:

On the begin of PHP Code (First tag):

```
ob_start();
```

On the end of PHP Code (Last Tag);

```
ob_flush();
```

Comment: To force redirection of pages, when multiples locations exist, and to prevent the warning which appears sometimes:Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/file.php:...) in /www/file.php on line ...

Comment: Yes, but why do you think that the javascript redirect was a problem?

Comment: Sometimes, the redirection with Javascript is blocked in server side for some statements and below the instructions and the position of code.

Comment: Javascript redirect blocked in server side?! That's not even possible.

Comment: Your code appears right, try to refresh your page after login (case right)

Comment: Yes but here there's no ajax request and also ajax headers block can be very easily bypassed. Let's just leave it like this, there's no need to spam this question with comments. Good luck!